# Getting connection abort and fatal alert error while recording in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am unable to record a script using JMeter and getting connection abort and fatal alert.

JMeter log:

```
2018-02-13 13:41:24,653 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54571]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.amplitude.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
2018-02-13 13:41:39,823 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54636]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'api.amplitude.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
2018-02-13 13:41:40,868 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54650]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'code.jquery.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this error is incorrect configuration of your browser, you need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into the browser, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you launch [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). See **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of JMeter User Manual for more information on the concept and instructions on how to install JMeter's certificate into different browsers. I would also recommend checking out [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) article for more details.

---

If your application doesn't use HTTPS and the call to `api.amplitude.com` is generated as a result of parsing embedded resources you can simply exclude this URL from recording by adding it to `URL Patterns to Exclude` field of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder like:

[image: JMeter exclude domain from load test]